# NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-280.13.run screwed up my sound

Tags: linux, audio, bios, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I just installed nVidia GT440 w/ NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-280.13.run driver on my Scientific Linux on two of my workstation and one of workstation sound disappeared.

Both workstations are identical though in terms of hardware and OS (Scientific Linux).

I'm not really sure where to look, but here is dmesg from workstation where sound **isn't** working: http://pastebin.com/tw29guqD

whenever I go to System -> Preference -> Sound -> Output on broken workstation I only see "HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)" and my old/onboard sound card is missing.

- UPDATE1:

I actually did roll out of same Video Card to more then just 2 workstation, I did that to a 5. Only 2 of them sound working as expected. 1 of them didn't even needed to install nVidia drivers but that workstation running slightly newer OS version 6.1 instead of rest 6.0, so I'm back to where I started it ... clueless ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found with some machines when you enable hdmi sound it will disable the onboard sound in the bios, it's happened to me under windows with ATi Cards but it could be the same issue.

Comment: right except i have more then 1 of exact same workstation running same Linux and behaves different, so there is something I can do to make it work...

Comment: With the issue I had you could reenable the onboard sound in the BIOS

Comment: i went to BIOS before I even post it, I couldn't find anywhere where it's enabled/disabled. i dont think it's possible to do on my BIOS

Comment: turns out, I was albe to somehow disable it inside of BIOS after all...